# Trouble getting the right output from a file

Tags: regex, linux, perl

Okay so here is my code:[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/ajc3cXEc)

What i want to do is read from the file /etc/passwd and extract all the users with an UID over 1000 but less than 65000. With those users i also want to print out how many times they have logged in. And with this current code the output is like this:

> user:15
>
> User:4
>
> User:4

The problem with this is that they haven't logged in 15 times or 4 times, because the program is counting every line that is output from the "last" command. So if i run the command "last -l user" it will look something like this:

```
user     pts/0        :0               Mon Feb 15 19:49 - 19:49  (00:00)
user     :0           :0               Mon Feb 15 19:49 - 19:49  (00:00)

wtmp begins Tue Jan 26 13:52:13 2016
```

The part that i'm interested in is the "user       :0" line, not the others. And that is why the program outputs the number 4 instead of 1, like it should be. So i came up with a regular expression to only get the part that i need and it looks like this:

```
\n(\w{1,9})\s+:0
```

However i cannot get it to work, i only get errors all of the time.
Im hoping someone here might be able to help me.

Comment: Don't use pastebin. Enter the relevant parts of the code here.

Comment: Which information do you actually need from this line? The whole line could be selected with [`^(user(?:\h+:0){2}.*)`](https://regex101.com/r/rU2yE6/1) for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this regexp will do what you want: `m/^\w+\s+\:0\s+/`

Here's some code that works for me, based on the code you posted... let me know if you have any questions!  :)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Modern::Perl '2009';    # strict, warnings, 'say'

# Get a (read only) filehandle for /etc/passwd
open my $passwd, '<', '/etc/passwd' 
    or die "Failed to open /etc/passwd for reading: $!";

# Create a hash to store the results in
my %results;

# Loop through the passwd file
while ( my $lines = <$passwd> ) {
    my @user_details = split ':', $lines;

    my $user_id = $user_details[2];

    if ( $user_id >= 1000 && $user_id < 6500 ) {
        my $username = $user_details[0];

        # Run the 'last' command, store the output in an array
        my @last_lines = `last $username`;

        # Loop through the output from 'last'
        foreach my $line ( @last_lines ) {
            if ( $line =~ m/^\w+\s+\:0\s+/ ) {
                # Looks like a direct login - increment the login count
                $results{ $username }++;
            }
        }
    }
}

# Close the filehandle
close $passwd or die "Failed to close /etc/passwd after reading: $!";

# Loop through the hash keys outputting the direct login count for each username
foreach my $username ( keys %results ) {
    say $username, "\t", $results{ $username };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the answer is to use

```
my @lastbash = qx(last $_ | grep ":0 *:");
```

in your code.

Comment: That will also grab the lines that have "pts/" between the user name and the ":0". He doesn't want those.

Answer (score 0):

The shortest fix for your problem is to run the "last" output through "grep".

```
my @lastbash = qx(last $_ | grep ' :.* :');
```